# Formula for returning first instance of partial text search for each row with multiple cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am in search for a formula that would check each cell in the row and return the first value the met the partial text search condition of AAS.

In the example below I am searching each row for the first occurrence in each row that starts with "AAS".

[image: Example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(A1:C1,MATCH("AAS" & "*",A1:C1,0))
```

Or:

```
=HLOOKUP("AAS" & "*",A1:C1,1,FALSE)
```

Or if you have Office 365:

```
=XLOOKUP("AAS" & "*",A1:C1,A1:C1,"",2)
```